# steam fresh function on my LG all in one

Tags: steam

Is there any way to disable the steam fresh function on my LG all in one washer/dryer? It builds up steam during the dry cycle and I am constantly burning myself.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is probably a question for LG tech support, or reading the manual. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: An all in one needs the water for the wash cycle maybe contact LG. Or provide the actual model number.